# Передача значений методом POST (checkbox)

Tags: php, массивы, post, checkbox

Есть скрипт для ввода и сохранения закладок. Закладки выводятся в таблице с тремя полями: адрес, категория закладки и checkbox (какие закладки добавить к себе). При выводе страницы рекоммендуемых закладок (recommend.php) всё отлично выводиться, нужные данные вытаскиваются из базы данных и подставляются в поля. Но, при попытке добавить новую закладку оттуда к себе на страницу, то добавляется только адрес, а категория нет.

Вот скрипт, который отрисовывает таблицы с закладками, которые можно добавить:

```
function display_recommended_urls($bookmarks_array)
{

  global $add_table;
  $add_table = true;

?>
  <br />
  <form name='add_table' action='add_recommend.php' method='post'>
  <table align="center" width=500 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0>
<?php
  $color = "#cccccc";
  echo "<tr bgcolor=$color><td><strong>Recommendations</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong>Category</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong>Add</strong></td></tr>";

  if (is_array($bookmarks_array) && count($bookmarks_array)>0)
  {

    var_dump($bookmarks_array); - **отсюда дамп**

    foreach ($bookmarks_array as $url)
    {   
      if ($color == "#cccccc")
        $color = "#ffffff";
      else
        $color = "#cccccc";

      foreach ($url as $bookmark => $category) {

      echo "<tr bgcolor='$color'><td><a href=\"$bookmark\">".$bookmark."</a></td>";
      echo "<td>".$category."</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name=\"add_me[]\" value=\"$bookmark\"></td>";
```

Если сделать var_dump($bookmarks_array), то результат следующий:

```
array(2) {

[0]=> array(1) { ["BOOKMARK_1"]=> string(4) "TEST" }  
[1]=> array(1) { ["BOOKMARK_1"]=> string(4) "TEST" } 

}
```

А вот обработчик предыдущего кода:

```
  $add_me       = $_POST['add_me'];
  $valid_user   = $_SESSION['valid_user'];

  do_html_header('Adding bookmarks');
  check_valid_user();
  if (!filled_out($_POST))
  {
    echo 'You have not chosen any bookmarks to add. Please try again.';

    display_user_menu();
    do_html_footer();  
    exit;
  }

  else 
  {
    if (count($add_me) > 0)
    {
      foreach($add_me as $url)

      {
        if (add_recommend($valid_user, $url))
          echo 'Added '.htmlspecialchars($url).'.<br />';
        else
          echo 'Could not add '.htmlspecialchars($url).'.<br />';
      }  
    }
    else
      echo 'No bookmarks selected for adding';
  }

  // get the bookmarks this user has saved

  if ($url_array = get_user_urls($valid_user))
    display_user_urls($bookmarks_array);

  display_user_menu(); 
  do_html_footer();
?>
```

Вот код, который создает сам массив закладок:

```
function get_user_urls($username)
{
  //extract from the database all the URLs this user has stored
  $conn = db_connect();
  $result = $conn->query( "select bm_URL, category
                          from bookmark
                          where username = '$username'");
  if (!$result)
    return false; 


  //create an array of the URLs 

  $url_array = array();

  for ($count = 0; $row = $result->fetch_row(); ++$count) {

      $bookmarks_array[$count] = array($row[0] => $row[1]);

   }

  return $bookmarks_array;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.. Как передать целый массив в обработчик, а не только ключ??

Comment: Из вашего вопроса ничего непонятно. Кто такой "обработчик", какой массив вам нужно туда передать и что за "ключ" там оказывается

Comment: Обработчик - это скрипт, который идёт 3-м в выложеных листингах. Он принимает и обрабатывает закладки, которые были выбраны для добавления к себе на страницу. Есть массив, элементами которого, в свою очередь, выступают ассоциатывные массивы. Каждый асс. массив имеет вид: "закладка" => "категория закладки". "Закладка", соответственно - ключ елемента, "Категория закладки" - значение елемента.